# how to add square which moves on the border transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

https://ibb.co/jWTW6T . <--- image of what I want to achieve

```css
.image-client {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-client-diamond {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
    position: relative;    
}

.image-client-diamond-inner {
    width: 69.5%;
    height: 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    padding-bottom: 69.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);

}
img {
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-client">
    <div class="image-client-diamond">
        <div class="image-client-diamond-inner hover-image-client">
            <img src="http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2009/09/photogalleries/new-hubble-camera-first-pictures/images/primary/090909-01-hubble-new-camera-upgraded_big.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXbWh.png)

How do I get a border transition animation with a mini square block which animate when you hover over this element. Only the orange block which has been shown on the enclosed image should be moving instead of the line itself.

Comment: What kind of border transition? How do you imagine the _mini square block_? How does it appears? How should be animated? You question is unclear to me

Comment: mini square block already appears, but it should be moving the entire border line

Comment: You can't do this with a transition or, simply with an animation. I'd suggest an SVG and a motion-path,,,but that's a lot more complex than what you are attempting.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NMmzWZ